# Присваивание внутри оператора return

Tags: c++

Я начал изучать систему непересекающихся множеств, но на сайте e-maxx.ru представлен только код на C++, а я знаю только Питон 3 и Паскаль. Вот непонятный мною код:

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dsu

```
int find_set (int v) {
    if (v == parent[v])
        return v;
    return parent[v] = find_set (parent[v]);
}
```

Интересует строчка `return parent[v] = find_set (parent[v]);`
Почему при возвращении присваивается значение переменной? Если возможно, прошу подсказать, как это можно написать на питоне или паскале

Comment: Это просто сокращение. Это тоже самое что и `parent[v] = find_set (parent[v]); return parent[v];`

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Comment: видимо нужен где такой "присваивание в return?"

Comment: @EOF, в упрощённом варианте - да, и в этом коде такая замена возможна. Но в общем случае в большинстве языков есть разница, поскольку второй вариант вызывает геттер, а первый - нет. Хотя, хотя бы [тут](https://ideone.com/IEbl0r) сюрприза нет.

Answer (score 2):

1. Потому что в Си(++) можно использовать присваивания в любых выражениях.
2. Потому что это удобно, когда изменение и дальнейшие действия в одном месте.
3. Переменная `parent` глобальная, так что присваивание имеет смысл.
4. Начиная с Питона 3.8 так тоже можно будет делать с помощью оператора `:=`.